# C++ Class object in stack inserted as value of Map

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, stack, heap-memory

I have two sample classes Sample and Hello

The Hello has a map which contains a map in heap, that map has Class Sample's object in it's value type.

```
class Hello
{
public:
    map<int,Sample>* samMap;
};
```

And my function has a code like this

```
Hello * h = new Hello;
{
    h->samMap = new map<int,Sample>;
    for(int i=0 ; i<100000;i++)
    {
        Sample se;
        se.a = i*2;
        se.b = i*5;
        se.vecInt = new vector<int>;
        se.vecInt->push_back(i+2);
        h->samMap->insert(make_pair(i,se));
    }
}
map<int,Sample>::iterator ss = h->samMap->find(50);
if(ss != h->samMap->end())
{
    cout << " Value : " << ss->second.a <<  " " << ss->second.b << endl;
    for(int s=0; s<ss->second.vecInt->size(); s++)
    {       
        cout << ss->second.vecInt->at(s) <<  endl;
    }
}
```

From the above code, the Sample object is declared and used inside a block. Once the control comes out of block the stack object have to get cleared.

But still i can iterate the map and get the Sample's objects outside the for loop without any access violation exception.How is that possible? While inserting the object to container a new copy of object is inserted ?

Comment: You should prefer value semantics (stop using `new` all over the place).

Comment: `h->samMap->insert(make_pair(i,se));` - you create a copy of `Sample se` and insert it into the map. Why do you expect the copy to be destroyed?

Comment: By the way *"access violation exception"* is not part of the C++ standard - accessing an invalid memory location (e.g.: via a dangling pointer) leads to *undefined behavior*

Comment: @UnholySheep Does this copy happen even if the Sample is a Struct instead of Class ?

Comment: `struct` and `class` are the *same thing* in C++ - the only difference is the default access modifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Because you're not storing a pointer or reference, a copy is made when you add it to the map.

Of course, if class Sample has a destructor to delete vecInt, it will also need a copy constructor; otherwise the pointer in the map's copy becomes invalid when the local "original" goes out of scope.

Comment: When I delete the vecInt in destructor of Sample, the application crashes even before I iterate the map to get object's values

Comment: That's because the map's internal processing likely requires making another copy, triggering a destructor for an already-deleted pointer. If you set vecInt to 0 in the destructor that crash likely goes away.

Comment: while strictly correct, this answer endorses and encourages bad style (`new` instead of value semantics).

Answer (score 0):

The correct way here is to avoid deep copies and use memory management support from the standard library: most usages of `new` are a sign of poor design. For example (I'm guessing a bit about the guts of `Sample`)

```
class Sample
{
    int a=0, b=0;
    std::vector<int> vecint;   // not a pointer, but data member
  public:
    Sample(int _a, int _b)     // construct sample with empty vecint
      : a(_a), b(_b) {}
    void add(int x)            // add to vecint
    { vecint.push_back(x); }
};

struct Hello
{
    std::map<int,Sample> samMap;
};

Hello makeHello()
{
    Hello hello;
    for(int i=0; i<100000; ++i)
    {
        auto r = hello.samMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                                      std::forward_as_tuple(i),
                                      std::forward_as_tuple(i*2,i*5));
        if(!r.second)
            throw std::runtime_error("couldn't insert new Sample for key '"+std::to_string(i)+"'");
        r.first->second.add(i+2);  // add to inserted Sample
    }
    return hello;
}
```

Note: no call to `new` and, consequently, no call to `delete`. It's all done under the hood by the standard library containers `std::map` and `std::vector`.

See also the documentation for [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and [`std::map::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace).